# Runtime and space usage of a snippet of code

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, space-analysis

I've been trying to understand time complexity and space complexity by writing my own snippets of code and solving them. Can you see if I'm correct?

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i*=2) c = i+8;
for(int j=n; j>0 ; j/=2) a[j] = 8;
```

I think the time complexity is $O(log_2n)$ and the space complexity is $O(n)$.

```
for(int i = 1; i<=n;i*=2)
    for(int j=n ; j>0 ; j/=2)
        a[j] = 8;
```

In this case, the time complexity is $O((log_2n)^2)$ and the space complexity is $O(n)$.

What do you think?

Comment: Are you expecting an "yes/no" answer? If you got that answer, you need to be able to justify them. What is your confusion?

Comment: Aim for $\Theta$.